# How to format a date in uppercase?

Tags: java, date, calendar, formatting

I'm trying to format a date in this way:

```
Monday 4, November, 2013
```

This is my code:

```
private static String formatDate(Date date) {
  Calendar calenDate = Calendar.getInstance();
  calenDate.setTime(date);
  Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
  if (calenDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
    return "Today";
  }
  today.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
  if (calenDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
    return "Yesterday";
  }
  // Guess what buddy
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE d, MMMMM, yyyy");
  // This prints "monday 4, november, 2013" ALL in lowercase
  return sdf.format(date);
}
```

But I don't want to use some `split` method or do something like that. Isn't there some pattern that I can include in the regexp to make it be uppercase at the begin of each word?

**UPDATE**
I'm from a hispanic country, something like `new Locale("es", "ES")` I get "martes 7, noviembre, 2013" when what I need is "Martes 7, Noviembre, 2013".

Comment: What locale are you using ? It should be fine with the US locale.

Comment: What locale are you using? That looks odd to me. Try explicitly setting the formatter's locale to US English, and ideally providing a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I already updated my question, I need a spanish locale, so I use `new Locale("es", "ES")`

Comment: Are month and day names normally written in uppercase in Spanish?

Comment: Not normally, but the client want it in that way.

Comment: Ah, clients who think they know better than the RAE... tends to happen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the strings that `SimpleDateFormat` outputs by setting the `DateFormatSymbols` it uses. The official tutorial includes an example of this:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormatSymbols.html

Reproduction of the example from the tutorial, applied to the "short weekdays":

```
String[] capitalDays = {
    "", "SUN", "MON",
    "TUE", "WED", "THU",
    "FRI", "SAT"
};
symbols = new DateFormatSymbols( new Locale("en", "US"));
symbols.setShortWeekdays(capitalDays);

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E", symbols);
result = formatter.format(new Date());
System.out.println("Today's day of the week: " + result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `Locale.US`, it works fine:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE d, MMMMM, yyyy", Locale.US);
System.out.println(sdf.format(Date.valueOf("2013-11-07")));
```

Output:

```
Thursday 7, November, 2013
```

Comment: Sorry I don't explain me myself very well. I'm from spain and I don't have any Locale.SPAIN, for example :/. If I use `new Locale("es", "ES"` I get something like "martes 7, noviembre, 2013" when what I need is "Martes 7, Noviembre, 2013". I'm updating the question now...